# Weak Convergence and Random Index

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X_n$ and $N_n$ are random variables ($N_n$ is integer-valued) such that   $(X_n, N_n/n)$ jointly weakly converges to $(X,1)$. There is NO assumption on independence between $X_n$ and $N_n$. Based on the paper:

*Aldous, David J. "Weak convergence of randomly indexed sequences of random variables." Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society. Vol. 83. No. 1. Cambridge University Press, 1978*

one needs an additional assumption on $X_n$ to conclude the weak convergence of $X_{N_n}$  to the distribution of $X$. However, suppose one uses Skorokhod representation, so that on the same probability space, we have  $(X_n^*,N_n^*/n)$ converges a.s. to $(X^*, 1)$. Then would not this imply that $X_{N_n*}^*\rightarrow X^*$ a.s. and hence conclude the weak convergence of $X_{N_n}$ to $X$? Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we know only that $(X_n, N_n) \overset{d}{=} (X_n^*, N_n^*)$ for every $n$, it does not follow that $X_{N_n^*}^* \overset{d} = X_{N_n}$. The distribution of $X_{N_n}$ depends on the entire joint distribution of $(N_n, X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots)$, which the Skorokhod construction does not necessarily preserve.

So even though $X_{N_n^*}^* \to X^*$ a.s., it does not follow that $X_{N_n} \to X$ in distribution.

For a trivial example, suppose $X_1 = N_2 = 0$, and that $X_2, N_1$ are each "coin flips" that are uniformly distributed on $\{1,2\}$, and that $X_2, N_1$ are independent. Let $X_1^* = N_2^* = 0$, let $X_2^*$ be uniformly distributed on $\{1,2\}$, and let $N_1^* = X_2^*$.  Then we have:

- $(X_1, N_1) \overset{d}{=} (X_1^*, N_1^*)$, as both pairs are uniformly distributed on $\{(0,1), (0,2)\}$
- $(X_2, N_2) \overset{d}{=} (X_2^*, N_2^*)$, as both pairs are uniformly distributed on $\{(1,0), (2,0)\}$
- $X_{N_1}$ takes the values $0,1,2$ with probabilities $1/2$, $1/4$, $1/4$ respectively
- $X^*_{N_1^*}$ takes the values $0$ and $2$ with probabilities $1/2$.